# Leaves turning brown?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, indoors, diseases

This is one of two indoor planta I bought a Walmart. It used to be nice, but then I noticed that the leaves are turning brown.

It’s not overwatering because I bought two of them and the other doesn’t have this issue.

What can it be? The last picture is of leaves that are just growing, but they are also turning brown/purple.

They’re in a balcony, so they don’t receive direct sun.

The weird thing is that I took it to my rooftop to water and left it upstairs all day. We live in the Caribbean so it’s 90+ deg F (and lots of sun) and it hasn’t recovered from that day.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you happen to know what kind of plants they are? If I had to guess, I’d think *maybe* (very, very *maybe*) a [hydrangea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrangea_macrophylla)?

Comment: And how long ago did you leave it on your rooftop? Just this one or both?

Comment: It was upstair just one day. From that day on it hasn’t recovered.